# Xpath for checkboxes without IDs

Tags: selenium, xpath

What xpath can I use for something like this without using ID? Or if there are more checkboxes but IDs are still different after refreshing page?

```
<td class="player" style="vertical-align: top;">
<span class="gb-CheckBox">
<input id="gb-uid-120" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<label for="gb-uid-120"></label>
</span>
</td>
```

Comment: There couple checkbox elements with same `HTML`, only `id` values are different? Could you clarify this moment?

Comment: Are you looking to find a particular `INPUT` or all of them or ???

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
//span[@class="gb-CheckBox"]/input[@type="checkbox"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
//input[@type='checkbox']
```

this should be enough and will select all inputs that are checkbox type.
If you need only from a certain area then you need to add a constraint by adding another selector in front of this like:

```
//div[@class='my_prefered_area']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

Another way of getting the selector would be to use the pare of the id that does not change like:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'gb-uid')]
```

Of course you can also add the restriction for checkbox type:

```
//input[contains(@id, 'gb-uid')][@type='checkbox']
```

Comment: I need to check if checkboxes are checked or not or sometimes click on some of them. But I have more checkboxes and all of them have the same class just ID is different, but its not fixed. And this is also in popup window and if I tried some of this xpath its checking checkbox on main page, not in my "popup" window.

Comment: You need to select that specific checkbox from pop-up. If you need to check them then see if you have any check() method ad create one if not.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you got the answer as most of the ways mentioned above are correct.

Correcting the first one path wit CSS :

```html
td.player>span.gb-CheckBox>input[type='checkbox']
```

(try it removing the spaces before and after > )

Or

```html
td.player>span.gb-CheckBox>input
```

Will also work.

As you mentioned, if your Id is changing frequently, that means its an dynamic webelement and 
if it is changing at the end(after gb-uid- i.e. gb-uid-120, then gb-uid-121 something like this) then use contains function on Xpath as below:

```html
//span[@class="gb-CheckBox"]/input[contains(@id, 'gb-uid-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also locate this checkbox easily using `cssSelector` instead of `xpath` which would be much faster as below :-

```
td.player > span.gb-CheckBox > input[type='checkbox']
```

Comment: Any explanation for down vote?? I know OP wants xpath but This would also work because selenium also support cssSelector to locate and element, and this is even better suggestion. So please provide needful comments if you are looking this answer is not correct. Thanks

Comment: down vote is not from me... but, I have tried it this way but it is not working for me...

Comment: @vb381 Could you share what do you mean it's not working?? is there any exception or something else?